# Is there a way to shorten nested for loops?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
for mesh in meshes:
    for primitive in mesh.primitives:
        print(accessors[primitive.attributes.POSITION])
```

Are there any ways to shorten this? I'm trying to make my code more compact and reduce the number of lines. I'm just wondering if there's a way to make this shorter.

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: You can use list comprehension `[print(accessors[primitive.attributes.POSITION]) for mesh in meshes for primitive in mesh.primitives]` but if you try this you also get an list containing None values. Try to print this list.

Comment: `print(*(accessors[primitivie.attributes.POSITION] for mesh in meshes for primitive in mesh.primitives), sep='\n')`

Comment: I don't recommend that. It does nothing than make code more unreadable.

Comment: Yes you can shorten this as shown in the excellent answer from @MechanicPig However, I would advise against it. Your code is very clear in terms of what it's doing. You are unlikely to gain any performance benefit by converting to a "one-liner". Also, if you're developing professionally, you need to think about maintenance of code. Why write something that's difficult to understand when what you have is functionally correct? You might want to test other options with respect to their relative performance. I have found that some "one-liner" variations run **slower** than traditional loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I adjust the repetition of for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72268044/how-can-i-adjust-the-repetition-of-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it as compact as possible use this.

```
lst = [accessors[primitive.attributes.POSITION] for mesh in meshes for primitive in mesh.primitives]

for a in lst: print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This outputs all contents at once by concatenating the string with newline character:

```
print('\n'.join(str(accessors[primitivie.attributes.POSITION]) for mesh in meshes for primitive in mesh.primitives))
```

Or decompress the generator into the print function and separate them with a newline character:

```
print(*(accessors[primitivie.attributes.POSITION] for mesh in meshes for primitive in mesh.primitives), sep='\n')
```

But it's best to use your original method. Compressing such a simple and readable behavior has no practical significance.

Answer (score 0):

If this loop gets repeated in your code, you can make a generator for it:

```
def premitive_gen(meshes):
    for mesh in meshes:
        for primitive in mesh.primitives:
            yield primitive
```

then you can use it like this:

```
for primitive in premitive_gen(meshes):
     print(accessors[primitive.attributes.POSITION])
```